# JSP: Simplest way to detect that the browser has "gone away"?

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

I have been asked to write a tiny Java based web application doing a job which can run for hours which can be implemented as a single JSP page with a calculate-print-flush loop.  This works fine.  Several independent calculations will run in parallel at the same time.

I would like to be able to detect that the user is not interested in the calculation any more (by closing the browser or reloading etc.) so I can interrupt and shut down the calculation properly.

Initial experiments with Jetty 9 as the container showed that the thread is not notified by the container that the browser in the other end stopped accepting output (testing with Chrome) instead of throwing an InterruptedException.

Its been a while since I did JSP's.  I can throw in a Javascript library snippet doing magic or something similar, but I need it to be container independent as I do not have control of the deployment container.

Any suggestions?

Comment: May be time to think about Aysnc servlets (or) comet, browser will be registered with server as client as long as it is up.

Comment: The target container is to my knowledge Java EE 1.4 compliant.

Comment: Jetty 9.1 is compliant to the Web Profile for Java EE 7.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt that is what I am using right now. The target container will not be jetty.

Answer (score 2):

AJAX?

Can't you try AJAX?  As you told about Javascript magic, I guess you can try that. Keep sending an AJAX (with time stamp) in an interval saying this user is alive. Once the request stops sending - you can assume he has gone! And thus you can close the thread.

Sorry if you feel this as funny, I am just a beginner.

Comment: Thats an absolut legitime way of archiving this in the async. World of HTTP. Requires however scripts enabled client side. BUT if thats no problem the gone client is recognized faster than waiting for a session timeout and would for example allow a programm to run over night with still a session timeout of just a couple of mins. Thats why i upvotet it back to 0, your input in my eyes is very good.

Comment: I have seen a message like "Do you really want to close the window ?" or something like that. see this example from our jsfiddle http://s3.amazonaws.com/awesome_screenshot/3299102?AWSAccessKeyId=0R7FMW7AXRVCYMAPTPR2&Expires=1384517987&Signature=tu9I3ehNuZbquIPxoGbzHVXklZ0%3D If this is possible , why cant you use that event to send an ajax call to server saying this user is signed out.

Answer (score 1):

Add a session listener. When the user logs out or the server notices that the connection to the browser is lost, it will eventually remove the session and invoke all session listeners.

Just set the session timeout to 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look into websockets. I am not sure if this is supported by your AS or if it makes sense for you application. If it seems too much and you just want something simple you could just use the `SessionListener` (Although you might be contained on the timeout), use a JSF library that provides AJAX Push or just write your own Ajax push.

e.g. Websockets `RemoteEndpoint.sendPing`
@See: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm